# Multiple leader lines on one annotation (non feature-linked)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, annotation

Is it possible to link multiple leaders lines to one piece of annotation?

I'm working in ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop Advanced with non-feature linked geodatabase annotation. I have hundreds of numbers labeling various polygons, but some polygons share a number. Instead of creating multiple numbers/annotations for each polygon I'd like to have one number with multiple lines pointing to each polygon.

So, in the image below, the number 5 corresponds to multiple polygons. Here I've moved 5 from it's ideal location to show that the second leader line is not connected to the number annotation. My workaround has been to create another piece of geodatabase annotation with a blank text string to serve as a placeholder for a leader line. The other option was to use map/graphic annotation to create the second leader line, but with the multiple disadvantages of not being in the same annotation feature class as the number annotation.

[image: A blank piece of annotation holding the leader line]

My goal would be for each piece of number annotation to be connected to multiple leader lines like appears below.

[image: Numbers correspond to multiple polygons]

Comment: Could you please add a specific question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very similar question was asked over at [Ask A Cartographer](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=160) and the answer was:

> There's not even a hard way to do this yet. If you've got a lot of
>   these, I would suggest making a line feature class and just add line
>   features for the leaders. You'll have a lot more control over where
>   the leaders meet the text as well.

There is also an ArcGIS Idea for [Multi-leader-line balloon/callout boxes](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008G45AAE) to which you could add your vote.

Comment: To workaround in ArcMap, one could manually draw linear element and change the symbol of the line element accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I do this all the time, using a rather crude workaround, but it works. I create multiple annotations on top of each other and point each to where I want leaders.
I then tweak size and drawing order to make things look right. In the case of balloon callouts, I will create tiny polygons with no border that match the annotation background color to cover up unwanted annotation borders that cross over leaders.