# Sharing labels and have multiple leader lines for like features in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling

I have many labels in ArcMap and want to use one label with multiple leaders to call out features whose labels would end up being the same. Is this possible?

As it is right now it is not possible for me to fit all labels without being able to do this.

Using arcmap 10.3

Comment: It is not possible with any built-in support.  All you can do is use a line feature class or graphics to link a single label to each feature and it is all manual.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41158/multiple-leader-lines-on-one-annotation-non-feature-linked

Comment: I have also stacked labels--keep most of them blank except for the top one with the actual label and have all of the leader lines from the labels underneath pointing to the proper locations.